# Fixed position sidebar being cropped in Safari on iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a fixed div which is set as a hamburger menu on my site. All is well and it hides perfectly when Chrome is resized, even using Chrome DevTools on my Windows machine.

When I uploaded my changes to my demo site, the div appeared fine until the 'menu' at the bottom slid down. As it was sliding, the element did not show until the transition had finished, then my fixed div resized.

I've tried using % and vh vales in CSS and tried resizing in JavaScript.

Is there a way to ignore the menu and make my fixed item always the same height?

[image]
[image]
[image]